# Woocommerce, get main product id

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm currently working on a WooCommerce plugin and attempting to get main product id from variable product.

If product has no variations i will use:

```
$product_id = $product['data'] -> get_id();
```

and it works.

But if I have product with variations i have problem to get main id (not id of variable product)

**e.g.**
Product id=10 has 2 variations with IDs 11 and 12, and if i add to cart product with id 12 i wanna get id of main product (id = 10).

I searched for an answer for a long time, but found nothing useful, so I turn here.
I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parent id from a variation like this for example..

```
$main_product_id = $variation->get_parent_id();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, this is what I was looking for! :) Thank you